# GraphQL relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm following the tutorials of Academind, so this video is my current standpoint:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRrcUQhZwBc

So my current code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const Event = require('./models/event');
const User = require('./models/user');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHttp({
    schema: buildSchema(`
        type Event {
          _id: ID!
          title: String!
          description: String!
          price: Float!
          date: String!
        }

        type User {
          _id: ID!
          email: String!
          password: String
        }

        input EventInput {
          title: String!
          description: String!
          price: Float!
          date: String!
        }

        input UserInput {
          email: String!
          password: String!
        }

        type RootQuery {
            events: [Event!]!
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event
            createUser(userInput: UserInput): User
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
      events: () => {
        return Event.find()
          .then(events => {
            return events.map(event => {
              return { ...event._doc, _id: event.id };
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          });
      },
      createEvent: args => {
        const event = new Event({
          title: args.eventInput.title,
          description: args.eventInput.description,
          price: +args.eventInput.price,
          date: new Date(args.eventInput.date),
          creator: '5c0f6dcde049d205fa2471dc'
        });
        let createdEvent;
        return event
          .save()
          .then(result => {
            createdEvent = { ...result._doc, _id: result._doc._id.toString() };
            return User.findById('5c0f6dcde049d205fa2471dc');
          })
          .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
              throw new Error('User not found.');
            }
            user.createdEvents.push(event);
            return user.save();
          })
          .then(result => {
            return createdEvent;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
          });
      },
      createUser: args => {
        return User.findOne({ email: args.userInput.email })
          .then(user => {
            if (user) {
              throw new Error('User exists already.');
            }
            return bcrypt.hash(args.userInput.password, 12);
          })
          .then(hashedPassword => {
            const user = new User({
              email: args.userInput.email,
              password: hashedPassword
            });
            return user.save();
          })
          .then(result => {
            return { ...result._doc, password: null, _id: result.id };
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    },
    graphiql: true
  })
);

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${
      process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD
    }@cluster0-ntrwp.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB}?retryWrites=true`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I have currently created events with a relation to a user. Now I want to get all events from a user.
Therefore I've found this article: https://devhints.io/graphql
I want to use the "Lookups", so my code for a request would be:

```
{
  events(_id: "5da717be4330150430fd770e") { _id }
}
```

But I am recieving this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"id\" on field \"events\" of type \"RootQuery\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But what do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no Query for getting specific `Event` with its `id`. Your "events" query does not accept any args and is expected to return an array of *Events*.

```
type RootQuery {
   events: [Event!]!
}
```

See the following example from the [docs](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/)

> ```
> type Query {
>   human(id: ID!): Human
> }
>
> type Human {
>   name: String
>   appearsIn: [Episode]
>   starships: [Starship]
> }
>
> enum Episode {
>   NEWHOPE
>   EMPIRE
>   JEDI
> }
>
> type Starship {
>   name: String
> }
> ```
>
> In order to describe what happens when a query is executed, let's use
>   an example to walk through.
>
> ```
> {
>   human(id: 1002) {
>     name
>     appearsIn
>     starships {
>       name
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Result
>
> ```
> {
>   "data": {
>     "human": {
>       "name": "Han Solo",
>       "appearsIn": [
>         "NEWHOPE",
>         "EMPIRE",
>         "JEDI"
>       ],
>       "starships": [
>         {
>           "name": "Millenium Falcon"
>         },
>         {
>           "name": "Imperial shuttle"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Take note of the example

```
type Query {
  human(id: ID!): Human
}
```

In your case, you will have to make something like that from above:

```
type Event{
  event(id: ID!): Event
}
```